# XSL for generating QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am generating qbxml using dom parser. I believe the qbxml need to be in such order. Is there any XSL is available for generating qbxml using xml parser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are XSD files available in the Validator directory included in the SDK. C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\Common\tools\validator